# Get closest locations with CoreLocation

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, geofencing

How can i get nearest locations for my current location like Instagram did before posting any item? I use CoreLocation for finding my current location with the code below. Now how can i use this CLLocation info class to get the nearest locations? Or which other options do i have to implement this feature? Any suggestion would be very helpful.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil){
            print("LoginView locationManager Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
            return
        }

        if (placemarks!.count > 0){
            let placemark = placemarks?[0]

            let latitude = String(format: "%f", (placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude)!)
            let longitude = String(format: "%f", (placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
            guard let local = placemark?.locality else { return }
            let uLocation = UserLocation(locality: local, longitude: longitude, latitude: latitude)
            self.userLocations.append(uLocation)
            self.locationContainer.setupData(locations: self.userLocations, delegate: self)
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    })
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Update : I decided to use Google Places SDK for iOS https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/intro for this purpose. It provides more flexible and reliable solution than the CLLocation does.

Comment: You need to do proper R&D before asking any quest. By the way you can do it by google place api.

Answer (score 0):

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil){
            print("LoginView locationManager Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
            return
        }

        if (placemarks!.count > 0){
            let placemark = placemarks?[0]

            let latitude = String(format: "%f", (placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude)!)
            let longitude = String(format: "%f", (placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
            self.addressDecoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {
                [unowned self] (result, error) in
                guard let address = result else { return }
                let nearbyName = address[0].name ?? address[0].locality
                let uLocation = UserLocation(locality: local, longitude: longitude, latitude: latitude)
                self.userLocations.append(uLocation)
            })
            let uLocation = UserLocation(locality: local, longitude: longitude, latitude: latitude)
            self.userLocations.append(uLocation)
            self.locationContainer.setupData(locations: self.userLocations, delegate: self)
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
        }
    })
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

I used `??` in case the address isn't found, then go with the *locality* as you have it right now. Play with the `result` inside the completion block to check the other options available in case one of them is appealing to you.

Regards.

Comment: @umutg4d Did you try this? 